# Core Label with "for" attribute does not associate with an input element

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have a `<core-label>` within a custom element which has a `for` attribute specifying class for an `<input>` within another custom element.  However, clicking on the core-label element does not put the focus in the target specified by "for".

Why? And how do I overcome this?

```
 <custom-one>
    <core-label for=".cls{{myObj.hashCode}}" type="checkbox">
    </core-label>
 </custom-one>

<custom-two>
    <input class="cls{{myObj.hashCode}}" type="checkbox">
</custom-two>
```

Please note:

1. myObj specified in both elements is same.
2. I have tried "for=" without
   the "." prefix too.
3. The html generated does have proper class in both places.

Comment: Have you tried without the binding in `for="..."` and `class="..."` but use a fixed class name instead?

Comment: I did. That too is not working.

Comment: Using fixed class name works for me with your example when there is only one element with that class. I'll now try with binding.

Comment: Works with binding as well. The only problem I run into while playing around was when more than one element existed with the class used in `for="..."`

Comment: You mean two labels that had the same value for the attribute "for" ?

Comment: No, the other way around :D. Two elements `for` would refer to. Two checkboxes (or other input elements or not input elements at all) with the same class you are using in `for`.

Comment: This is what I had suspected too to be at the root of the problem. In my application, it is dynamically decided, which kind of input element to generate, using the polymer `if` attribute. Therefore there are 4 versions in the polymer element, even though eventually only one gets generated in html.

Comment: `template if=...` removes the content if the expression is `false` so this should be fine. Maybe it's a timing issue, that the label is already bound to the input element and then it is removed and another one is added/shown (just a wild guess - I don't know enough about your code to know)